# how to convert the curl command to implement it in pycurl? or any alternative to os.system

Tags: python, json, curl

curl -u username:password -X POST -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d @test.json http://x.x.x.x:111/vs

tried to run the above using 
os.system(curl -u username:password -X POST -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d @test.json http://x.x.x.x:111/vs)

getting "bad request" as response

how can i implement this using pycurl?
or is there any other subprocess that i can use,

I am working on windows

Answer (score 0):

I'd do that in this way if I were you:

```
curl_cmd = '''
curl -u username:password -X POST -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d @test.json http://x.x.x.x:111/vs
'''
os.system(curl_cmd)
```

If you want to use pycurl, the you can see the example of [how to post data using pycurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/doc/quickstart.html#sending-form-data). Along with this post data you'll need to add authentication (user:pass) and you can do is in this way:

```
userAndPass = b64encode(b"username:password").decode("ascii")
pycurl.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Authorization' : 'Basic %s' %  userAndPass])
```